# Each clause is not working after Template Name change

Tags: html, meteor, each, clause

I don't understand why the each clause is not working after I add the template "simple-todos" around them?!

```
<template name="simple-todos">
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <header>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
        {{> addObjects}}
    </header>
  <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
          {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</template>

<template name="task">
    <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
        <button class="delete">&times;</button>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
        <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
        <span class="text">{{createdAt}}</span>
    </li>
</template>
```

When I'm not using the template name "simple-todos" I became directly the values from the database...

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to put `head` and `body` tags inside a Meteor template, use this approach instead :

HTML

```
<!-- HEAD and BODY must be top level tags -->

<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> simpleTodos}}
</body>

<template name="simpleTodos">
  <div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```